# How to stack divs each with 100% height

Tags: css, html, height, stack

I am really pulling my hair out over this one, I cannot get 100% height divs to stack vertically. I have searched around and tried several variations but none have worked. Please help!

You can see an example [here](http://demo.venomvendor.com/pure-css-menu/) (This is not my site)

```html
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">
</div>

<div class="home">
    <p>Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between     the Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
</div>

<div class="work">
    <p>Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
</div>

<div class="about">
    <p>Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
</div>

<div class="contact">
    <p>Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

----- CSS ----

```css
*{
margin:0px;padding:0px
}

html{
height:100%
}

body{
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden
}       

.wrapper {
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
height:100%
}

.home {
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
padding:50px 50px 0 50px;
position: absolute;
background: red;
}

.work {
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
padding:50px 50px 0 50px;
position: absolute;
background: aqua;
}

.about {
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
padding:50px 50px 0 50px;
position: absolute;
background: blue;
}

.contact {
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
padding:50px 50px 0 50px;
position: absolute;
background: black;
}
```

Comment: There is normally not really a problem doing that. Where is your html and css code?

Comment: I see a page with 4 buttons. When i click those button the page scrolls upwards and another page with really eye-popping color comes on screen. same thing happens with all 4 buttons. WHere are the divs???

Comment: I made a mistake clicking those button's. My eyes are hurting now. Dude, seriously. change those colours before you do anything else

Comment: Please provide the code for what you have tried

Comment: @Tony, your stacking issue is because you are using position absolute, they will all be `top:0; left:0` which means they will be placed on top of each other.  The example site is using javascript to stack them properly and get that scrolling effect when you click the buttons

Comment: @Pete is there anyway to do it without javascript and just CSS? Should I position them relative?

Comment: just take the absolute positioning off, but you won't be able to see the others as you have overflow:hidden on the body.  remove this to be able to scroll to the other divs.  Or this is a simple version of the other page using css only - it just doesn't scroll to the next page (you may be able to do something with css3 transitions for that)  http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hnmf3/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

update html ,css and include js

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jwwFx/2/)**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="home" class="home content">
            <p>
                Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the
                Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official
                name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="work" class="work content">
            <p>
                Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the
                Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official
                name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="about" class="about content">
            <p>
                Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the
                Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official
                name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact" class="contact content">
            <p>
                Denali is the highest mountain in North America. Due to a disagreement between the
                Boards of Geographic Names in Alaska and the United States, the peak's official
                name is Denali according to Alaska and Mount McKinley according to the United States.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="floating-menuV">
        <a class="scroll button" href="#home">Home</a> <a class="scroll button" href="#about">
            About</a> <a class="scroll button" href="#work">Works</a> <a class="scroll button"
                href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
```

css

```
*
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body
        {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .wrapper
        {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .content
        {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 50px 50px 0 50px;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        .content p
        {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 50px 50px 0 50px;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        .home
        {
            background: red;
        }

        .work
        {
            background: aqua;
        }

        .about
        {
            background: blue;
        }

        .contact
        {
            background: black;
        }

        @font-face
        {
            font-family: 'SansNarrow';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsansnarrow/v3/UyYrYy3ltEffJV9QueSi4RdbPw3QSf9R-kE0EsQUn2A.woff") format('woff');
        }


        a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li
        {
            list-style: none;
        }

        img
        {
            border: none;
        }

        h1
        {
            color: #000052;
            position: fixed;
            margin-top: -50px;
        }


        .floating-menu
        {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 20px;
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 41px;
            left: auto;
            right: 23px;
            background: #F7F5F3; /* Fallback */
            background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 1); /* Change the Tranparency */ /* background: transparent; */ /*Overrides the bg to transparent */
            -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
            -moz-border-radius: 14px;
            border-radius: 14px;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #05C4FF;
        }

        /* Comment while using horizontal */
        .floating-menuV
        {
            float: right;
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: auto;
            right: 23px;
            background: #F7F5F3; /* Fallback */
            background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 1); /* Change the Tranparency */ /* background: transparent; */ /*Overrides the bg to transparent */
            -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
            -moz-border-radius: 14px;
            border-radius: 14px;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #05C4FF;
        }

        .floating-menu a
        {
            font-size: 19px;
        }

        nav.floating-menu h3
        {
            display: block !important;
            margin: 0 0.5em;
        }

        nav.floating-menu a
        {
            margin: 0.5em;
        }
        /* Comment while using vertical */
        nav.floating-menu a.hor
        {
            display: block;
        }

        .button
        {
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 99px;
            -moz-border-radius: 99px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 99px;
            background: #FF0000;
            color: #fff;
            border: 3px #fff solid;
            background-color: #e7676d;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e7676d),
        to(#b7070a) ); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e7676d, #b7070a); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e7676d, #b7070a); /* FF3.6 */
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e7676d, #b7070a); /* IE10 */
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e7676d, #b7070a); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e7676d, #b7070a);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#e7676d',
        EndColorStr='#b7070a' );
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#e7676d, endColorstr=#b7070a)";
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000; /* Saf3-4 */
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000; /* FF3.5 - 3.6 */
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, FF4+, Chrome 10+ */
            display: inline-block; /* Main Adjustments */
            padding: 5px 10px;
            margin: 5px 10px; /* Main Adjustments */
            transition: all .8s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all .8s ease !important;
            -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
            -o-transition: all .8s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
        }

        .button:hover
        {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all .4s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all .4s ease !important;
            -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
            -o-transition: all .4s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
            background: #9FC500;
        }
```